# big difference between r squared in training and test data

Tags: regression, random-forest, scikit-learn

I'm building a random forrest regression tree and use `cross_validate` function from scikit-learn with `cv=3` I'm getting a huge difference bewtween the r squared in training and test sets, e.g. [0.55449074, 0.58333731, 0.59569356] are the r squared for training and [-0.13157146,  0.05355582, -0.00551714] are the values for r squared for test. What can be the problem here?

Comment: Looks like classic [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)

Comment: and it can be because of redundant features or the configuration of the tree, e.g. max_depth, num_estimator etc? I'm guessing of the later as the tree implicitly does the feature selection

Comment: The negative R-squared (R2) values are puzzling. If you manually calculate using "R2 = 1.0 - (numpy.var(modeling error) / numpy.var(dependent data))" do you get the same values?